# Is it possible to run Railcraft with Optifine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-railcraft, minecraft-optifine

I want to install railcraft 1.7.2 WITH Optifine (1.7.2) but apparently the two have a problem with each other, if I take out railcraft, it runs fine with optifine, if I run it without optifine and with railcrqaft, railcraft runs fine. I also have 3 other mods installed (one being buildcraft which is connected with railcraft making it more confusing) and they run fine with optifine (yes, I know, a lot of "fines" here). Anyways, does anyone know how to make the run together, or is it simply impossible?

Here is the crash report:

---- Minecraft Crash Report ---- // My bad. Time: 7/17/14 12:08 AM Description: Stitching texture atlas java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureAtlasSprite.func_147965_a(TextureAt‌​lasSprite.java:217) at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.func_110571_b(TextureMap.java:3‌​55) at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.func_110551_a(TextureMap.java:1‌​21) at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_110579_a(TextureManage‌​r.java:94) at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_110580_a(TextureManage‌​r.java:76) at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_130088_a(TextureManage‌​r.java:63) at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:523) at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:815) at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:103) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134) at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------‌​------- -- Head -- Stacktrace: at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureAtlasSprite.func_147965_a(TextureAt‌​lasSprite.java:217) -- Texture being stitched together -- Details: Atlas path: textures/blocks Sprite: TextureAtlasSprite{name='railcraft:anchor.admin.0', frameCount=0, rotated=false, x=416, y=512, height=0, width=0, u0=0.40625978, u1=0.40624022, v0=0.5000098, v1=0.49999022} Stacktrace: at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.func_110571_b(TextureMap.java:3‌​55) at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap.func_110551_a(TextureMap.java:1‌​21) -- Details: Resource location: minecraft:textures/atlas/blocks.png Texture object class: net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureMap Stacktrace: at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_110579_a(TextureManage‌​r.java:94) at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_110580_a(TextureManage‌​r.java:76) at net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.TextureManager.func_130088_a(TextureManage‌​r.java:63) at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:523) -- Initialization -- Details: Stacktrace: at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:815) at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:103) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134) at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) -- System Details -- Details: Minecraft Version: 1.7.2 Operating System: Windows Vista (x86) version 6.0 Java Version: 1.7.0_65, Oracle Corporation Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode, sharing), Oracle Corporation Memory: 128987952 bytes (123 MB) / 396222464 bytes (377 MB) up to 518979584 bytes (494 MB) JVM Flags: 2 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.‌​heapdump -Xmx512M AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0 FML: MCP v9.03 FML v7.2.217.1147 Minecraft Forge 10.12.2.1147 Optifine OptiFine_1.7.2_HD_D1 15 mods loaded, 15 mods active mcp{9.03} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized FML{7.2.217.1147} [Forge Mod Loader] (forge-1.7.2-10.12.2.1147.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized Forge{10.12.2.1147} [Minecraft Forge] (forge-1.7.2-10.12.2.1147.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized CodeChickenCore{1.0.2.10} [CodeChicken Core] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized NotEnoughItems{1.0.2.14} [Not Enough Items] (NotEnoughItems-1.7.2-1.0.2.14-universal.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized TConstruct-Preloader{0.1.1} [Tinkers Corestruct] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized BuildCraft|Core{6.0.16} [BuildCraft] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized BuildCraft|Builders{6.0.16} [BC Builders] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized – BuildCraft|Energy{6.0.16} [BC Energy] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized BuildCraft|Factory{6.0.16} [BC Factory] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized BuildCraft|Transport{6.0.16} [BC Transport] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized BuildCraft|Silicon{6.0.16} [BC Silicon] (buildcraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized Mantle{1.7.2-132.45b0b50} [Mantle] (Mantle-1.7.2-0.2.8.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized Railcraft{9.0.0.0} [Railcraft] (Railcraft_1.7.2-9.0.0.0.jar) TConstruct{1.7.2-1.6.0.jenkins478} [Tinkers' Construct] (TConstruct-1.7.2-1.6.0.a14.jar) Unloaded->Constructed->Pre-initialized Mantle Environment: DO NOT REPORT THIS CRASH! Unsupported mods in environment: optifine TConstruct Environment: Environment healthy. Launched Version: 1.7.2-Forge10.12.2.1147 LWJGL: 2.9.0 OpenGL: Intel Cantiga GL version 2.0.0 - Build 7.15.10.1576, Intel Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge' Type: Client (map_client.txt) Resource Packs: [] Current Language: English (US) Profiler Position: N/A (disabled) Vec3 Pool Size: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)

---

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's for modded minecraft tech support and we can only help with vanilla minecraft crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Download OptiFine 1.7.2_HD_U_D3 (fixed compatibility with Railcraft and IC2, compatible with Forge #1147): [Download](http://adf.ly/404181/optifined.net/adloadx.php?f=OptiFine_1.7.2_HD_U_D3.jar), mirror (07.07.2014)

Download the above link as you can see it is a fixed version of optifine takne from the [Minecraft Forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1272953-optifine-hd-a4-fps-boost-hd-textures-aa-af-and)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the mods folder of the "Modpack" that you are using then in to 1.7.2 folder and there  **DELETE** the WorldCore file. Then launch minecraft launcher with Optifine mod placed in the mods folder and launch Minecraft. 
*Before you launch this modpack next time remember that you have to* ***AGAIN DELETE*** *the WorldCore file.*